# When formatting a long negative number with several decimal places to 3 decimal places it is displaying as 0.00 instead of -0.00

Tags: javascript, angular

With a number like  `-0.000086350795672884042562015`

I am formatting it using [Angular Percent Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/PercentPipe): `percent:1.2-2`

It is displaying as `0.00.`

Is there any way to make it display as -0.00? 
(I am not sure what kind of rounding it is doing.)

Comment: The number 0 is neither positive nor negative. Any number plus zero or any number minus zero is the same thing, so what exactly are you trying to do and why does it matter that there's no `-` sign before the zero?

Comment: @Mike IEEE FP has +0 *and* -0 - most programming languages simply gloss over the difference, as it's usually awkward to run into those '0 not equal 0' or 'negative 0' cases D: However, there is a difference .. and, as in the case above, the ask is to preserve said information (in the to-string case there is not even an implicit 'to 0' first).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [Intl.NumberFormat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) to achieve this.

This should do the trick:

```js
let num = -0.000086350795672884042562015;
let formatted = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2}).format(num);

console.log(formatted);
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks! any idea why what i was doing with percent:1.2-2 isn't basically the same thing as per the documentation?

Comment: Not too sure but it looks like it converts it to a percentage string, although the base functionality is quite similar to `Intl.NumberFormat()`